# MySQL query not giving results as expected

Tags: mysql

Below are two mysql tables. I want to check if the two people are in teams from Table: Teams and then getting their name and email from Table: Registration. I am having a hard time writing a mysql query for it.

Table: Registration

```
id: 1      name:jason        email:jason@xyz.com
id: 2      name:kim          email:kim@xyz.com
id: 3      name:tim          email:tim@xyz.com
```

Table:Teams

```
team_id: 1      person1Id: 1       person2Id: 2
team_id: 2      person1Id: 1       person2Id: 3
```

Comment: that is worse to read ansd use as the first

Comment: Also in teams should shoufd be the ids, there maybe 40 Kims in the Registration table

Comment: @nbk sorry thats what i meant. Teams will have userId instead of their names.

Comment: and please how should the result should be like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to join the registration table twice and give them a unique alias

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE Teams (
  `team_id` INTEGER,
  `person1Id` VARCHAR(9),
  `person2Id` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO Teams
  (`team_id`, `person1Id`, `person2Id`)
VALUES
  ('1', '1', '2'),
  ('1', '1', '3');

CREATE TABLE Registration (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `name` VARCHAR(5),
  `email` VARCHAR(13)
);

INSERT INTO Registration
  (`id`, `name`, `email`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'jason', 'jason@xyz.com'),
  ('2', 'kim', 'kim@xyz.com'),
  ('3','tim','tim@xyz.com');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
    t.team_id,r1.name,r1.email,r2.name,r2.email
FROM Teams t
INNER JOIN Registration r1 ON t.person1Id = r1.id
INNER JOIN Registration r2 ON t.person2Id = r2.id;

| team_id | name  | email         | name | email       |
| ------- | ----- | ------------- | ---- | ----------- |
| 1       | jason | jason@xyz.com | kim  | kim@xyz.com |
| 1       | jason | jason@xyz.com | tim  | tim@xyz.com |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4yPorU6k3SjQ5nmhgi1wGo/39)

Comment: INNER JOIN Registration r1 ON t.person1Id = r1.id
INNER JOIN Registration r2 ON t.person2Id = r2.id  Can I use OR after this to check the opposite combination?

Comment: no you can't use or, that why i added registration twice.

Comment: qand plase vote up and accept valid answer that helped you

Comment: It did not work. I will try to play with it and report with an update. Thanks for the help

Comment: what didn't work exactly? you can male a dbfiddle and i will have a look

Comment: that worked! I think there might have been an error on my end which was why it wasnt working. But now it does now that you elaborated more on your answer. Thank you

Comment: How can I manually enter numbers in place of r1.id and r2.id so i can test it on mysql before taking it into my code block?

Comment: i use mysql workbench to access my database, but there is also phpmyadmin and their query tabs. but i made a dbfiddle, there you can play around with by inserting new lines.

Comment: So I updated my question. Basically with one team it worked. But what about the same person in team1 is in teams with another member and I only want to see those two people? See above in my updated question

Comment: that really doesn't matter, that is made row by row, as you can see in the changed answer, please use the dbfiddle to experiment and make a new question, if soemthing is unclear

Answer (score 0):

you can select both ids from Teams table and use `in` clause to get name and email from Registration table as

`select name, email from Registration where id in(select person1Id, person2Id from Teams where team_id=1)`